# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require (emulator on Windows 10)

Tags: android-emulator, react-native, genymotion

I am having issues when running the command: react-native run-android --emulator

My build is successful, but when it comes up on Genymotion I get: 
[image]

Nothing even happens on android AVD: 
[image]

I have ran the following command with no changes: adb reverse tcp: 8081 tcp:8081

I am on Windows 10, using emulators (not my device). Also, I had someone who has a Mac run this with **no issue**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update!

Turns out for Windows 10 I need to have two prompts.

One needs to be running: react-native start

The other: react-native run-android OR react-native run-android --emulator